# Responsive Square Grid with borders 1px

Tags: grid, responsive-design

I was wondering if it's possible to create a responsive web grid full a width of 1200px, with an exact border of 1px on each square of the grid.

You can see what I'm trying to do here:

http://machinas.com/wip/machinas/website/grid/

I'm using fluid squares for this:

http://fluidsquares.com/

I set each square to bg-color white, and the wrapper around has a bg-color grey, and each square has margin in percentage to give it a border but it doesn't give exact 1px border. Anyone know if it's possible somehow?

this is what the code is so far for each square:

```
a {
    margin: 0.1% 0.1% 0 0;
    padding-bottom: 15%;
    width: 16.56%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

0.09% will give 1 pixel border ( closest as you can get )

```
a {
    margin: 0.09% 0.09% 0 0;
    padding-bottom: 15%;
    width: 16.56%;
}
```